# Async storage cannot retrieve data from react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, local-storage, asyncstorage

I am using AsyncStorage to keep user data to phone. After registering the user, i am trying to retrieve the user if exist one and automate redirect to profile page.
but I have problems with async storage because it returns only the word 'user' in the console...

in the login component ->
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

```
const loggedUser = async () => {
    try {
        const u = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
        console.log(u);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

```
/**
 * 
 * This function retrieve the data from the server and store it to the local database..
 * 
 */

const executeLogin = async (email, password) => {
    try 
        {
            // Get data and store in async storage
            const response = await data.post('/api/login', {email, password});    
            storeData('user', response.data); -> //Check the code bellow for the source
        } 
        // Catch all errors bellow
        catch (error) 
        {
            if (error.response.status === 404 && error.response.data === 'Wrong credentials') {
                Alert.alert('Whoops!', 'You entered the wrong credentials. Please try again.');
            }
            else {
                Alert.alert('Whoops!', 'Something went wrong. This is an unexpecred error. We will try to fix it as soon as possible');
            }
        }
};

export default executeLogin;
```

The code block above calls the axios and supose to store the data to async storage. But I have no ideea also if it worked because it gave me no error...

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

/**
 * 
 * This function must only accept serialised object with JSON.stringfy() method
 * 
 */
const storeData = async object => {
    try 
    {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', object);
    } 
    
    catch (error) 
    {
        console.log(error);
    }
} 

export default storeData;
```

This is the store function

Cannot understand what I am doing wrong....
Thanks, Daniel

Comment: Have you actually tried using JSON.stringify(response.data) before saving to the local storage?

Comment: Is already stringfied. I received the response as a string and didn't modified it. 
```
const response = await data.post('/api/login', {email, password});
```
returns stringfied object from the server

Comment: Can you try setting a plain string, like setItem("user", "Hello world"). What happens then?

Comment: I am only getting a log of the key. 
only "user". Even with the plain text.

I took those function from the official link... 
is it a graphical tool to check for that DB like the local storage for the browser where I can check the records?